# How to override Sentinel Activation (using Laravel)

Tags: laravel, activation, sentinel

For the most part, I want all users to have to use the activation checkpoint when registering for my site.

There are some occasions where I would like to bypass this, some thing like

```
Activation::setToTrue($user);
```

Is there a good way to do this that you know of?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have to register them first, then if they have a mobile, I'm using Nexmo to validate and then if that succeeds I need to override the activation but without knowing the code (because I obviously don't want to store on the session).

So I've ended up with this crude solution which can't be right can it?

```
        \Activation::remove($user);
        $activation = \Activation::create($user);
        \Activation::complete($user, $activation['code']);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this to activate on registration using sentinel-

```
Sentinel::registerAndActivate();
```

Or you could do this like following by `bypassing` existing user object. First you need to `check` if any `activation record exists` for this user or not. Then do the necessary steps to `complete` the activation according to your need.

```
$activation = \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation::exists($user);
if($activation){
    Activation::complete($user, $activation->code);
}
else{
    $activation2 = Activation::create($user);
    Activation::complete($user, $activation2->code);
}
```